# When pulling data from the Internet in Python, product names are None, product prices repeat themselves. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm just learning the Python language. I'm trying to extract information from a site selling cell phones from the internet using the BeautifulSoup library. I was able to pull the relevant links of the site. But there is a problem like this. When I pull the product information, although I use the same code logic and codes, the output becomes none. When I get the price information, the prices come in duplicate. Below are the codes that I wrote according to the site's review code.

[image]

This Pic. LABEL INFORMATION I SHOULD USE TO TAKE THE PRODUCT PRICE OF THE SITE
This Pic. LABEL INFORMATION I SHOULD USE TO TAKE THE PRODUCT NAME OF THE SITE

[image]

And my code like this;

```
url = "https://www.teknosa.com/cep-telefonu-c-100001"

response = requests.get(url)
html_icerik = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerik, "html.parser")
for j in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "price-tag new-price font-size-tertiary"}):
    price = j.get("content")
    print(price)

url = "https://www.teknosa.com/cep-telefonu-c-100001"
response = requests.get(url)
html_icerik = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerik, "html.parser")
for k in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"product-name"}):
    name = k.get("span")
    print(name)
```

How can I solve this problem? When I search for related classes, the names are None, the prices are repeated twice. It has always been done this way on the Internet. I could not find how to move forward. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues. Namely, you shouldn't need to invoke `requests.get` more than once, but that's more of a performance issue. With regards to parsing, methods such as `get` will fail if the item you are getting isn't an immediate child of the invoking element. In such cases you should use `find` as an alternative. Here is updated code that is more concise. You can edit this to your specific needs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.teknosa.com/cep-telefonu-c-100001"

response = requests.get(url)
html_icerik = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerik, "html.parser")
for j in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "product-item"}):
    namediv = j.find("div", attrs={"class": "product-name"})
    namespan = namediv.find("span")
    name = namespan.getText()
    pricespan = j.find("span", attrs={"class": "price-tag new-price font-size-tertiary"})
    price = pricespan.getText()
    print(f"Name: {name}\tPrice: {price}")
```

Output:

```
Name: Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra White Akıllı Telefon  Price: 12.999 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra Bronze Akıllı Telefon Price: 12.999 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra Black Akıllı Telefon  Price: 12.999 TL
Name: Apple iPhone 11 64GB White Akıllı Telefon Price: 7.899 TL
Name: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 4GB/64GB Mavi Akıllı Telefon  Price: 2.999 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy  A01 Black Akıllı Telefon  Price: 1.899 TL
Name: Oppo Reno 2Z 128GB Gece Mavisi Akıllı Telefon Price: 3.999 TL
Name: Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro 6-128GB Gri Akıllı Telefon    Price: 4.099 TL
Name: Oppo Reno 3 128GB Kuzey Işıkları Akıllı Telefon   Price: 4.399 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy A71 128GB Siyah Akıllı Telefon Price: 4.299 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy A51 White  Akıllı Telefon  Price: 3.999 TL
Name: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro 6GB/128GB Yeşil Akıllı Telefon    Price: 3.699 TL
Name: Apple iPhone 8 Plus 128GB Gold Akıllı Telefon Price: 6.549 TL
Name: Huawei P40 Lite 128 GB Pembe Akıllı Telefon   Price: 3.499 TL
Name: Huawei P30 Lite 128 GB Midnight Black Akıllı Telefon  Price: 2.999 TL
Name: Samsung  Galaxy A31 Blue Akıllı Telefon   Price: 3.499 TL
Name: Samsung Galaxy A01 Blue Akıllı Telefon    Price: 1.899 TL
Name: Apple iPhone SE 64GB Red Akıllı Telefon   Price: 5.299 TL
Name: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 4GB/128GB Siyah Akıllı Telefon    Price: 3.199 TL
Name: Apple iPhone 11 64GB Purple Akıllı Telefon    Price: 7.899 TL
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much. I am learning new Python. and I don't know truly Web Scraping. Thanks for help. I solved my problem thanks to your support.

Comment: Well, if I entered these information in excel, I entered under the following conditions and there was no problem. Since I bought it from Teknosa at the beginning of each line, how can I write Teknosa then name and price. If I need to give an example about my essay, I write Teknosa in 20 columns between A1 - A20. But B1 - B20 also return the same name. B21 is the second name @h0r53

Comment: If you want to save this and load it into Excel I'd recommend using Comma Separated Values (CSVs), which Excel should be able to read easily. Just remove `Name: ` in the example I provided and replace `Price: ` with a comma.

Comment: Thank you for help, ı am learning and understand thanks to you @h0r53